# Accordian: Arrow image not displaying even though image path is correct

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, css

I want the arrow-collapsed image to be displyed before accordian headers and when accordian header is clicked and expanded, arrow-collapsed image should change to arrow-expanded image. What am I doing wrong below? Also, image paths are all correct. I have checked many times.

my accordian:-

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true"  Visible="true" AutoSize="None"SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false"  TransitionDuration="250" 
HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader toggler" ContentCssClass="accordionContent expanded toggler">
                <HeaderTemplate>

                    <b style="color: Black">

                        <%#Eval("Ques")%>
                    </b>

                </HeaderTemplate>


                <ContentTemplate>
                <p> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuesAns")%></p>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:Accordion>
```

**css**

**Am I giving the CSS Class names incorrectly or what ????**

**@denis..its still not displaying the images..cant find the images in Firebug either**

Comment: 3 thinks, first I think is better to use the .css("background-image", "url(/images/arrow-expanded.png)"); and not full change of the class name, second remove the quotes ", from the url, third inspect you css using the inspection tools to see what css final give to your object. If you do not know where to find the inspection tools, use google or firefox, right click and "inspect elements"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest to take a look at [Accordion](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx)  sample page which lists all available properties along with their descriptions. You'll notice that the Accordion also exposes `HeaderSelectedCssClass` property - this is where you set a style for the collapsed state. So, you could re-write your markup like so:

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true" Visible="true" AutoSize="None" SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false" TransitionDuration="250" 
     HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader toggler" 
     HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeader toggler-expanded" 
     ContentCssClass="accordionContent"> 
        <HeaderTemplate> 

            <b style="color: Black">    
                <%#Eval("Ques")%> 
            </b> 

        </HeaderTemplate>        

        <ContentTemplate> 
            <p> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuesAns")%></p>        
        </ContentTemplate> 
 </cc1:Accordion>
```

And for CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .accordionHeader {         
        cursor: pointer;         
        margin-top: 10px;         
        margin-left: 20px;
    }         

    .toggler {
        background: url('../../images/arrow-collapsed.png') no-repeat left center transparent;
    }         

    .toggler-expanded {
        background: url('../../images/arrow-expanded.png') no-repeat left center transparent;
    }

    .accordionContent { 
         margin-top: 10px;         
         margin-left: 20px;         
    }   
  </style>
```

And please remove all those scripts.

Comment: @denis..its still not displaying the images..cant find the images in Firebug either

Comment: I've updated the CSS a bit.. just tested in FF and it works fine. Are you sure the images are placed in the correct path? You can review the "Net" tab in Firebug to see if there are any issues retrieving the icons (non-200 status).