# Jquery accordion: How do I get rid of these scroll bars for good?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, css

I have set the attribute in my accordion AutoSize="None", even then when I click on some headers, scroll bars are being displayed. How do I get rid of these scroll bars for good?

please check my accordion code here

[Accordian: Arrow image not displaying even though image path is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468110/accordian-arrow-image-not-displaying-even-though-image-path-is-correct)

**my accordion:**

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true"  Visible="true" AutoSize="None"SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false"  TransitionDuration="250" 
HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader toggler" ContentCssClass="accordionContent expanded toggler">
        <HeaderTemplate>

            <b style="color: Black">

                <%#Eval("Ques")%>
            </b>

        </HeaderTemplate>


        <ContentTemplate>
        <p> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuesAns")%></p>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </cc1:Accordion>
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained.  You should repost whatever code is relevant here.

Comment: ok lemme paste here again then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways to avoid the scrollbar.

1. To set **overflow=hidden** on the divs that you gets them http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow
2. To set a little less size on the inner divs that show them. For example, set on the HeaderTemplate **width=98%**, so its always a little less and no see the scollbar. Why the less size is hide scollbar, because the scrollbar some times is made because the one div is too big to fit the father div, and the father div create scollbar to show it all.

hope this help.

Comment: I got it sorted..thnx :) could u plz help me out with this another accordian problem? I'd be grateful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468110/accordian-arrow-image-not-displaying-even-though-image-path-is-correct